# Is defining repetitive Orage events by date possible?

Tags: calendar, gtk, xfce

I'm a big fan of the Orage Calendar (for XFCE), but I can't seem to find how to define repetitive events by date:

I need to define an event that:

- Repeats monthly
- on fixed day numbers (say, on the 1rst, 8th, 15th, and 22nd)

Is this possible?